# Prove that $ax^{6}+bx^{5}+cx^{4}+dx^{3}+ex^{2}+fx+g=0$ has at least two opposite sign real roots.

Tags: calculus, integration, polynomials, definite-integrals, roots

Prove that:

$ax^{6}+bx^{5}+cx^{4}+dx^{3}+ex^{2}+fx+g=0$ has at least two opposite sign real roots when $\frac{a}{4}+\frac{c}{3}+\frac{e}{2}+\frac{g}{1}=0 $ and $\frac{b}{7}+\frac{d}{5}+\frac{f}{3}=0$.

---

By using MVT, I want to find $F(x)$ that is the antiderivative of $f(x)=ax^{6}+bx^{5}+cx^{4}+dx^{3}+ex^{2}+fx+g$ satisfying that $F(-1)=F(0)=F(1)$. However, I can't use  $\frac{a}{4}+\frac{c}{3}+\frac{e}{2}+\frac{g}{1}=0 $ and $\frac{b}{7}+\frac{d}{5}+\frac{f}{3}=0$ in finding $F(x)$.

Please help me! Thank you very much!

Comment: Consider finding the primitive of the product between $x$ and your polynomial $p(x)$, evaluated by separating the resulting product into terms of even respectively odd degree, and resorting to the $y=x^2$ change of variable when integrating the *odd* part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $$\int\limits_{-1}^0xf(x)dx=\int\limits_{0}^1xf(x)dx=0$$